# Partially encrypted installation

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, encryption, lvm

**Noob alert: slowly ditching windows. Speak slowly.**

With that out of the way, I want to install **Kubuntu 20.04** on a single dedicated SSD with an encrypted root&swap *but* I want to keep some free space so that I can add a new partition without encryption to store some VM images (which have already their own encryption).

- The installer (with the encrypted LVM option) can only use the whole disk with no option to leave some free space.
- I also search how to shrink encrypted LVM and it looks quite hairy to me.

Is there a simpler way to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To *somewhat* answer my own question, I gave a spin to the Debian installer which can do exactly what i want (and much more) with the partitioning and encryption. Then slapped KDE on it and I feel it is close enough to home (Kubuntu).